# Java Regex finding a substring without using space character in the pattern string?

Tags: java, regex

I have a string with the value `AB-CD>AY-ZV (FG)`. Out of this, I would like to get only the value `AB-CD>AY-ZV` using regex.

In this, I do not want to use space `\s` as part of my pattern.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you really need regex? `new Scanner("AB-CD>AY-ZV (FG)").next()` will return what you want. Also why not use `\s`? `"AB-CD>AY-ZV (FG)".split("\\s")[0]` will also give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below regex to match the first part.

```
String s = "AB-CD>AY-ZV (FG)";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^\\S+").matcher(s);
if(m.find())
{
System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Here `\\S+` matches one or more non-space characters and `^` asserts that we are at the start.

Comment: You should nt be using \s as part of your pattern

Comment: /s and /S are different. Sorry I can't post backslash.

Comment: @Deepan Then what can you use? Maybe instead of `\s` use simply space. If you also can't do that then please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28736797/edit) and explain why because it will mean that you are trying to solve [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Like this: "(\\w+-*\\w+)(>)(\\w+-*\\w+)"